# Django template error after parenthesis added by autoformat

Tags: django, django-templates, vscode-extensions

I use VSCode and the Django Template Support extension for autoformatting templates.
It adds parentheses to my code making it not work.

before:

```
{% elif n > page_obj.number|add:'-5' and n < page_obj.number|add:'5' %}
```

after:

```
{% elif n > (page_obj.number|add:'-5' and n < (page_obj.number|add:'5')) %}
```

```
Template error:
In template N:\Coding Projects\poc\templates\poc\product_list_grid.html, error at line 133
   Could not parse some characters: |(page_obj.number||add:'-5'
   123 :               <a class="page-link" href="?page=1" aria-label="First">
   124 :                 <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
   125 :                 <span class="sr-only">First</span>
   126 :               </a>
   127 :             </li>
   128 :           {% endif %}
   129 : 
   130 :           <!-- with filter and pages in between -->
   131 :           {% for n in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
   132 :             {% if request.GET.item_code or request.GET.brand__brand_name or request.GET.description %}
   133 :                {% if n == page_obj.number%} 
   134 :                 <li class="page-item active">
   135 :                   <span class="page-link"><b>{{ n }}</b><span class="sr-only"></span></span>
   136 :                 </li>
   137 :               {% elif n > (page_obj.number|add:'-5' and n < (page_obj.number|add:'5')) %}
   138 :                 <li class="page-item">
   139 :                   <a class="page-link" href="{% update_url n 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ n }}</a>
   140 :                 </li>
   141 :               {% endif %}
   142 : 
   143 :               <!-- without filter and pages in between -->
```

Is this a formatter issue? How can I solve this?
Removing the parenthesis worked but then I have to do that to all my templates.

Removing the parenthesis worked but then I have to do that to all my templates.

Comment: This is a very weird behavior I also faced in the past when using formatter. It would be great if you revert all changes made by formatter.